# Twitterizer twitter search not returning all the tweets it should

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitterizer

I'm have a twitter component on my site which uses a service to retrieve tweets. It allows for filtering by hashtags. However, it's not retrieving all the tweets that it should.

```
SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions { NumberPerPage = pageSize };

OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens()
{
    AccessToken = "xxx",
    AccessTokenSecret = "xxx",
    ConsumerKey = "xxx",
    ConsumerSecret = "xxx"
};

TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> twitterResponse = Twitterizer.TwitterSearch.Search(tokens, twitterQuery, searchOptions);
```

The `twitterQuery` I'm using is "from:myTwitterAccount #exampleHashtag". It's getting one result. However, if I go to twitter and paste that query into the search bar, there is a long list of results.

Is there a problem with Twitterizer? The only option that I have set is NumberPerPage, and that's set to 3, and other hashtags return more than 1 result. Why would some tweets show up in the twitter search but on get retrieved by my code?